# Accessing Heroku Postgres Database online

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

I am working on a Heroku project that is sending data to a Postgres database. I was hoping to make a second website that could pull data from that database and visualize it. However, I can't seem to figure out a way to make another web app (in Python/Flask) that can pull the data from this database. Is there anyway to access a Postgres database online (like a web link I can create to query it?) or should I look into using a different database setup?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [Heroku Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), which is Heroku's "Database as a Service" add-in offering based on PostgreSQL, you can [share a single Heroku Postgres DB between multiple Heroku apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#sharing-heroku-postgres-between-applications).